# Error when I try to window an audio file with FFT in matlab

Tags: matlab, window, fft

I'm trying to use the FFT algorithm to plot a graph of a simple audio voice file with magnitude against frequency, It works BUT I'm trying to window the signal for the purpose of removing the frequency leakage on the side lobes of the main frequencies. It is just giving me an error

here is the code without the windowing (which works):

```
[x,fs]=audioread('E:\voice_hum.wav');

x1=x;

plot_points = 100000;
h=fft(x1,plot_points);
freq = h(1:50001);    %dump data after half FS
mag = abs(freq);
freq = 0.5 * fs *(0:50000)/50000;    %frequency on x-axis
plot(freq,mag)
```

here is the code when I tried implementing a hamming window:

```
[x,fs]=audioread('E:\voice_hum.wav');

x1 = x(1:100);

w = hamming(100);
plot_points = 100000;

x1 = x1.*w';  %window the signal
h=fft(x1,plot_points);
freq = h(1:50001);  %dump data after half FS

mag = abs(freq);
freq = 0.5 * fs *(0:50000)/50000;

plot(freq,mag)
```

it is giving me this error:

> Error using  .*  Matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> Error in lab8b (line 12) x1 = x1.*w';  %window the signal

I'm a little confused about it, does someone know what I should do?

Comment: Consider using [`pwelch`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/signal/ref/pwelch.html) instead of implementing windowing and averaging yourself.

Comment: Although from the filename (`lab8b.m`) I see that this is homework. (-:

Comment: yeah I'm very new to these concepts, the homework wasn't solving this problem, the homework was doing the whole thing :P (just in case you thought I was trying to get people to do homework for me) I don't want to tread on anyone's toes here

Answer (score 1):

You are using dot-multiplication between w (a column vector) and x1 (a column vector, if you have only one audio channel).

In order to multiply two vectors with dot-multiplication (i.e. `a.*b`) they should have the same dimension, while you are using `a.*b'`, which is dot-multiplying a column and a row.

So you can either use `x1'*w` ([matrix multiplication](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html)) or `x1.*w` with the very same result.

Comment: I see,  I never thought about it that way, that I was multiplying a column by a row, but it does make sense now

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `you can either use x1*w (matrix multiplication) or x1.*w with the very same result.`?  If `x1` and `w` are row vectors, `x1.*w` will give the desired result, but `x1*w` will give an error.  Element-wise multiplication always has to be explicit, with the exception of multiplication by a scalar.

Comment: You are right. It should be a multiplication between a row and a column, therefore you need `x1'*w`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `x1 = x1.*w;` instead. Always remember to check your array dimension before the operation.